# What would happen if Wolverine stopped eating?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, x-men-days-of-future-past

Canon wise... if Wolverine stops breathing he doesn't die but rather goes into a coma like state (*X-Men: Days of Future Past*).

However, what would happen if he were to stop eating? Life cannot exist without energy, and while Logan hasn't as far as I know to be shown eating he does drink (albeit alcohol).

So would Logan die, go into a coma, or repair himself, if he were to stop eating?

Answers from any of the Marvel comics will also be accepted.

Comment: IDK how/if ever comics have addressed this, but normal human bodies when starving start digesting their own muscle masses for fuel: the same would probably happen to Wolvie, but being Wolvie he'd be able to continue regenerating his muscle mass and hence probably never run out of muscle mass to cannibalize. Meaning he'd continue digesting and regenerating himself infinitely until he got some food. No worries for this dude at all.

Comment: @Shisa Auto-cannibalism

Comment: Does this mean he doesn't need to eat?

Comment: @Jared No not really. But I doubt that cannibalising yourself is a very pleasant experience. Most likely scenario is that his body would reach a kind of equilibrium between self-digestion and regeneration. While he won't slip into a coma, he will be severely weakened and loose his a lot of his physical conditioning. He would, and this is merely speculation, probably look and act like an opium user: Very thin, always tired and everything seems hazy and out of focus. He eats mostly to stay in shape.

Comment: My mutant knowledge is poor so I'll leave the answer to someone who does know. But don't mutants draw their power from an alternate dimension (this is how they get around not having enough energy to do what they're doing). If wolverine doesn't eat does the energy come from there to sustain him?

Comment: @Shisa but that muscle being regenerated would require energy and mass to become regenerated... which would come from "digested muscle". Unless you play the "magic!" card or somethink like that, the regeneration of the muscle would make Wolverine need still more energy, meaning more muscle being digested and, in a word, making the process way quicker.

Comment: @SJuan76 - his regeneration defies physics so, yes, "magic!" is probably quite a reasonable answer under the circumstances/.

Comment: Don't make him hungry. You wouldn't like him when he's hungry. (Or is that the wrong superhero?)

Answer (score 6):

Wolverine eats. There are scenes of him eating food with others, for example in Original Sin #1. While he can go into a coma to survive, he becomes more or less brain dead. Wolverine has said that he survived for months under a glacier by eating strips off his arm. I think he mentioned this when talking to Jean Grey while they were trapped on asteroid M during Morrison's Planet X: [New X-Men Vol 1 #148](http://marvel.wikia.com/New_X-Men_Vol_1_148)

So I think even if he does starve, he doesn't die from it. He probably becomes weakened to the point of passing out and slipping into a coma. He does get hungry and, pushed to the limit, will feed on his own flesh to survive.

Chances are that he must do it slowly: cutting, eating, waiting to heal, and then repeating only in dire straits. The act of healing has to take energy so it probably becomes less effective over time. He is still expelling some as waste and the guy still feels pain.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of whether consistently starving him would result in his death

Comment: @Richard If I had to guess then I'd say that if he starved for a long enough period of time, then a lack of energy to even heal himself could cause him to die. The period would probably have to be in centuries or millennia for this to happen. But as I said, this is just guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

If Deadpool is any indication, Wolverine would be okay. Deadpool, who has a lower healing factor compared to Wolverine at this time, was buried in rubble for 800 years, and came out no worse for wear. This is during the X-Force arc.

Comment: It's worth noting that Deadpool's healing factor has been both from a mutant talent, and occasionally also from a mystical source, due to Thanos being jealous about Deadpool's relationship with Death.